# asynsPipe produces null as a first value

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

When using async pipe in Angular that don't fire event immediately(http request or any observable with a delay), got first value as `null`
Why is it happening? How to avoid that?

```
<hello [data]="delayedData$|async"> </hello>
```

First change:

```
SimpleChange {
   currentValue: null
   firstChange: true
   previousValue: undefined
}
```

Second change:

```
SimpleChange {
   currentValue: 'some real data'
   firstChange: false
   previousValue: null
}
```

Example on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-async-pipe-crxm32

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior judging from the implementation of the [`async`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bbeac0727b8f267a47aba1ff1bcfc8cc5ca15b61/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L73) pipe?

Comment: you can simply use 'startWith' operator, as you are using in the one of your observable, the outcome is actually logical, since observable does not hold any initial value, it prints null, try operator startWith, or it's variation @Muhammed Albarmavi wrote down here (I would suggest to use startwith), I know you might have much complex data structure in your real life code but, you can pass empty array empty object etc. as well

Comment: If you dive into the implementation – you can expect it, but there is nothing in official dos, and IMHO it's very strange behaviour – I'm expecting only the values from my observable, without sideeffects

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behaviour. To avoid it you can use the `*ngIf` directive:

```js
<hello *ngIf="delayedData$|async as delayedData" [data]="delayedData"> </hello>
```

This will only render the `hello` component only when the `delayedData$` has emitted a value.

[Angular docs on ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: this is a nice solution, but the problem is not to render element only when data comes, but be sure that what am I getting in an input is a data that i got from backend.

Comment: @KaterinaPavlenko `but the problem is not to render element only when data comes`? I do not understand that statement. Can you clarify what you mean.

Comment: your solution let me render the component only when delayedData$ produces not-null value. It is good, but what if delayedData$ _can_ produce null values and it is the normal behaviour of it? And I want to render component not depending on value produced by delayedData$?

Comment: long story short – I want to work with @Input data in ngOnChanges() and divide _default_ null from real null

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="delayedData$ | async; let item">
  <hello name="Observable emitting with a delay" [data]="item" > </hello>
</ng-container>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-async-pipe-pzlby1?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: this is nice idea, but the solution from this answer is shorter, doing the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249460/4166537

Comment: Yep, I was going to add this as another option, but since I saw someone already added it, I didn't mention :)

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use 'startWith' operator, as you are using in the one of your observable, the outcome is actually logical, since observable does not hold any initial value, it prints null, try operator startWith, or it's variation @Muhammed Albarmavi wrote down here (I would suggest to use startwith), I know you might have much complex data structure in your real life code but, you can pass empty array empty object etc. as well

Comment: aggred the startWith is the correct one and other answers is just a work arround 

Answer (score 1):

a simply whay to provide a default value until the request is done

```
<hello 
name="Observable emitting with a delay" 
[data]="((delayedData$|async) || 'hello from earth ')"> 
</hello>
```

[**demo ⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-async-pipe-cedcj9)

Comment: this might be solution as well, but it behaves absolutely same as startwith operator, but start with opereator is much cleaner way to achieve same result

Comment: @LashaSumbadze yes it just an alternative way but I think all answer can work very well  

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug of an Angular, explained in this issue(marked as proposal, but it is a bug)
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16982

Possible solutions are listed in this discussion. In general the solution is to use `startWith` rxjs operator, use `?.` in templates.

Also there is a tslint rule for preventing situations like that http://codelyzer.com/rules/template-no-negated-async/