# Initializing boolean value input properties in Angular 12 using async?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a boolean valued input property in an Angular 12 app that looks like this:

```
  @Input()
  isTOSAccepted: boolean = false
```

And in the template I'm attempting to set the value like this:

```
[isTOSAccepted]="oftrue | async">
```

The `oftrue` property is declared like this:

```
oftrue:Observable<boolean> = of(true)
```

The template linter creates the following error:

```
Type 'boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ngtsc(2322)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: "Thoughts?" isn't exactly a high quality question. The value emitted by an AsyncPipe is initially null, but the typing already told you that.

Comment: Also note research is required. Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61681239/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249409/3001761, ...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right.   I remember you telling me and I was searching for the question ... but I think it got cleaned up or something ... Anyways hopefully this stays in place ... otherwise you might see me back here in a few days :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output for AsyncPipe is T | null, so you will possibly need to handle a default value like:

```
{{ (oftrue | async) || false }}
```

The linter is complaining because your input is of type boolean and the async pipe returns the union type of T and null